# Make character always face the mouse cursor

Tags: rust, trigonometry, game-development, bevy

I found and tested many different implementations when searching for this topic, but my use case seems to be slightly different from others.

I have a static camera, but the player can move freely around the screen.

When the player is at the centre of the screen, my calculation kind of works fine, as seen below.

[image: player at centre]

However, when I move the player to a corner (bottom right corner in this case), it doesn't face the cursor. Seems like the calculation is ignoring the player's position, and only taking into consideration the cursor position in relation to the window.

[image: player at bottom right corner]

My code is implemented in Rust (with Bevy Engine), but I'm sure the logic can be adapted from any language.

```
let window_size = Vec2::new(window.width(), window.height());
let difference = mouse_position.extend(0.0) - window_size.extend(0.0) / 2.0 - player.translation;
let angle = difference.y.atan2(difference.x) + PI;

*transforms.get_mut(game.player.entity.unwrap()).unwrap() = Transform {
    translation: player.translation,
    rotation: Quat::from_rotation_y(angle),
    ..default()
};
```

Note1: `.extend(0.0)` converts it from Vec2 to Vec3 by adding 0.0 as `z`.

Note2: `player.translation` is a Vec3 with the player's position on the screen.

Comment: It seems like the camera angle is not perfectly flat with the game world. I suspect it is looking at your cursor, but the point it is above on the xz plane is behind the camera. You can fix it by doing two transforms. First you need to convert the screen space coordinates of the mouse to the world space. This can then be done a second time at a different depth to get a ray of possible points the mouse could occupy in the world. You can get the intersection of this ray with the ground plane to discover where the character should face.

Comment: @Locke what you said is very likely to be true, given I copied the logic from a 2d game. I wasn't familiar with "Raycasting", I just googled it and I believe this might be the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Locke, it doesn't seem to be a matter of tweaking my calculation, but there's a whole implementation missing: **Ray Casting**, which is required for 3d applications to be able to translate mouse coordinates into a 3d world position. For Bevy and Rust I found the following lib that seems to provide this functionality:

https://github.com/aevyrie/bevy_mod_raycast